# Variable won't pass between Python scripts

Tags: python

For some reason, I am not able to pass variables from one to another Python file.  Please see files below.

`pullgps.py`:

```
from lenny1 import * 
import time

while (1):

  print lenny1.lat
  print lenny1.lon
  print ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
  time.sleep(6)
```

`lenny1.py`:

```
import gps

# Listen on port 2947 (gpsd) of localhost
session = gps.gps("localhost", "2947")
session.stream(gps.WATCH_ENABLE | gps.WATCH_NEWSTYLE)

while True:
    try:
        report = session.next()
        # Wait for a 'TPV' report and display the current time
        # To see all report data, uncomment the line below
        # print report
        if report['class'] == 'TPV':
             if hasattr(report, 'lat'):
                  lat = report.lat ### export to pullgps
             if hasattr(report, 'lon'):
                  lon = report.lon ### export to pullgps
    except KeyError:
        pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        quit()
    except StopIteration:
        session = None
        print "GPSD has terminated"
```

`lenny.py` works fine on its own when I print `report.lon` and `report.lon`.  Just not able to export the variables to `pullgps.py`.  It should be simple, but for some reason, the variables just will not pass.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you should read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) about the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `from lenny1 import *` which imports everything from lenny1.py into the global namespace.  Not only that, but you're actually running everything in lenny1.py on the first import, which contains a while loop that could potentially block.  This is really bad code practice.  However, I think the problem you're having is that you are referencing `lenny1.lon` and `lenny1.lat` while using a starred import.  Just print `lon` and `lat` and it should in principle "work" provided the loop terminates.

Comment: Thanks, did as you mentioned.  It just hangs.  Changed to import lenny1 and removed the while loop.  It still hangs.

Comment: Which while loop did you remove? The one in lenny1.py looks like it will be blocking forever.

Comment: Also, are you planning to run the two processes concurrently? Because this is not the way to do it, as pointed out by user3591723 (comment now deleted).

Comment: Removed the loop in pullgps.py .

Comment: Right, then you should not expect your code to work. You probably have to look into threading or multiprocessing to get something that does what you want. But it won't look anything like what you have currently.